# Did Taskmaster actually adopt others' fighting skills?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, marvel-cinematic-universe, black-widow

In *Black Widow*, Taskmaster is noted for her ability to adopt (or mimic) fighting skills.  Throughout the movie, she displays fighting skills similar to that of many *Avengers* characters.

However, in the movie, we find out that she is...

> ...controlled by a chip implanted in her neck.

Thus, I'm not sure if she actually learns fighting skills through observation, or if...

> ...her fighting is orchestrated by software in the chip in her neck.

It seems plausible that without her suit, she is not able to fight (or, at least, not able to adopt the fighting styles of other fighters).

**Question**: Did Taskmaster actually adopt others' fighting skills?

Comment: There is literally a shot where you can see her "computer vision" where it analyses Black Widow's technique and "learns" it.

Answer (score 5):

Taskmaster is a "perfect mimic"; she has the ability to copy the moves of other fighters once she's seen them.

Dreykov boasts that he had to install the chip to be able to keep Antonia (Taskmaster) alive, and that was when he discovered she could mimic others. Near the end of the film, Natasha breaks the mind control on her and she stops fighting immediately.

Dreykov never mentions using the chip to implant fighting skills - if that were the case, he would be doing so with all of the Widows rather than just training them in the Red Room.

Comment: If the chip also affects cognition (Taskmaster seems little more than a zombie while controlled), then it's not much use for sleeper agents and infiltration, which is the Widows' primary purpose.